# conflict with Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.9 on MAC

Tags: python

It seems my mac has multi-version of Python

```
python            python2.6-config  python3           pythoni           pythonw2.6
python-config     python2.7         python3.3         pythoni1          pythonw2.7
python2.6         python2.7-config  python3.3-config  pythonw           pythonw3.3
```

Now the packages installed by PIP will be installed in Python 2.7.5

But the default Python is 2.7.6 , so I can not find the package when I use python shell.

How to fix it ?

```
% pip install pandas                                                                         (git)-[feature/support-python-with-ruby-python]
...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)
Cleaning up...

[15:25:55](~/workspace/flyberry_projects/03-CFTC-COT/COT/lib)
% python                                                                                     (git)-[feature/support-python-with-ruby-python]
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` is not MacPorts' usual default path - it's `/opt/local`. Are you sure you don't have a Homebrew version of Python in there as well, that `pip` is connected to? Also, `pandas` is available as port `py-pandas`, in case you don't feel like fixing `pip` ATM...

Comment: actually I have no idea what's going on. i can not import the package after pip install.

Comment: Are you open to using virtualenv?